# MongoDb - Update all properties in an object using MongoShell

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

I have a collection with many documents containing shipping prices:

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f7439c3bc3395dd31ca4f19"
  },
  "adapterKey": "transport1",
  "pricegrid": {
    "10000": 23.66,
    "20000": 23.75,
    "30000": 23.83,
    "31000": 43.5,
    "40000": 44.16,
    "50000": 49.63,
    "60000": 50.25,
    "70000": 52,
    "80000": 56.62,
    "90000": 59,
    "100000": 62.5,
    "119000": 68.85,
    "149000": 80,
    "159000": 87,
    "179000": 94,
    "199000": 100.13,
    "249000": 118.5,
    "299000": 138.62,
    "999000": 208.63
  },
  "zones": [
    "25"
  ],
  "franco": null,
  "tax": 20,
  "doc_created": {
    "$date": "2020-09-30T07:54:43.966Z"
  },
  "idConfig": "0000745",
  "doc_modified": {
    "$date": "2020-09-30T07:54:43.966Z"
  }
}
```

In `pricegrid`, all the properties can be different from one grid to another.

I'd like to update all the prices in the field "pricegrid" (price * 1.03 + 1).

I tried this :

```js
db.shipping_settings.updateMany(
  { 'adapterKey': 'transport1' },
  { 
    $mul: { 'pricegrid.$': 1.03 }, 
    $inc: { 'pricegrid.$': 1}
  }
)
```

Resulting in this error :

```
MongoServerError: Updating the path 'pricegrid.$' would create a conflict at 'grille.$'
```

So I tried with only $mul (planning on doing $inc in another query) :

```js
db.livraison_config.updateMany(
  { 'adapterKey': 'transport1' },
  { 
    $mul: { 'pricegrid.$': 1.03 }
  }
)
```

But in that case, I get this error :

```
MongoServerError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.
```

Could you please direct me on the correct way to write the request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an aggregation pipeline in an update. `$objectToArray` `pricegrid` to convert it into an array of k-v tuple first. Then, do a `$map` to perform the computation. Finally, `$arrayToObject` to convert it back.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "adapterKey": "transport1"
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      pricegrid: {
        "$objectToArray": "$pricegrid"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "pricegrid": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$pricegrid",
          "as": "p",
          "in": {
            "k": "$$p.k",
            "v": {
              "$add": [
                {
                  "$multiply": [
                    "$$p.v",
                    1.03
                  ]
                },
                1
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      pricegrid: {
        "$arrayToObject": "$pricegrid"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nHFPKONrwQ8) for your reference.

Comment: Thank you, that did exactly what I was waiting for. I used to work with MySQL a lot and I'm not familiar with the Mongo aggregation pipeline yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Aggregation framework:

- `$objectToArray` - to transform **pricegrid** object to array so you can iterate of its items
- `$map` to iterate over array generated in previous step
- `$sum` and `multiply` to perform mathematical operations
- `$arrayToObject` to transform updated array back to object

```
db.collection.update({
  "adapterKey": "transport1"
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "pricegrid": {
        "$arrayToObject": {
          "$map": {
            "input": {
              "$objectToArray": "$pricegrid"
            },
            "in": {
              k: "$$this.k",
              v: {
                "$sum": [
                  1,
                  {
                    "$multiply": [
                      "$$this.v",
                      1.02
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  "multi": true
})
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OaajrBdM8-o)

Comment: Thank you for your explainations. I accepted Ray's answer as it was posted a few minutes before yours, but upvoted your's too.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but it looks like there's currently no support for this feature - there's actually an open [jira-issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-267) that addresses this topic. Doesn't look like this is going to be implemented though.